Must ssh-add two times when over SSH
I am on an Ubuntu machine. When I login normally from my desktop, my SSH credentials are added automatically and everything works correctly.
However, when I instead work remotely via SSH, initially at login my SSH credentials are not loaded. For this reason, I have the following script, which I run manually, that calls ssh-add so that I can work normally:
#!/bin/bash

[[ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" == "${0}" ]] && echo "You need to source this!" && exit 1

# We don't actually need this since we have gnome-keyring-daemon
# killall ssh-agent
# gnome-keyring-daemon

if ! pgrep -f gnome-keyring-daemon; then
    echo "Failed, trying to startup gnome-keyring"
    gnome-keyring-daemon
    ssh-add -l
fi
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

However, for some reason, I generally have to trigger the script two times. The first time, I generally get a message like
> . ~/Scripts/loadSSH.sh 
2918
Enter passphrase for /home/svalorzen/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/svalorzen/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/svalorzen/.ssh/id_rsa)

And then git and other tools work correctly. However, after a few seconds, it breaks down, and I have to re-run the script, this time with the following output:
> . ~/Scripts/loadSSH.sh
Failed, trying to startup gnome-keyring
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
[... some keys ...]
Enter passphrase for /home/svalorzen/.ssh/id_rsa:

After the second time, I never have to run it again. What is the reason for this? Do I have to change the script or configure something in a different way?

In the first place, where are you ssh-add'ing the keys to? What is SSH_AUTH_SOCK set to? Does it even point to gnome-keyring at the time? (Your script, with the "must be sourced" notice, looks like it should be setting SSH_AUTH_SOCK to the path where gnome-keyring's agent listens... but the code posted doesn't do anything like that.) Second, have you inspected the system after it "breaks down" – is there a gnome-keyring-daemon process still running? (And a corresponding ssh-agent underneath it in the process tree?)

In both cases, SSH_AUTH_SOCK is set to /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh. I forgot to check if the daemon process is running manually last time (I'll try next time), but if pgrep doesn't find it doesn't it mean that it is not there?

@grawity Seems gnome-keyring-daemon is still running after the first failure. Today I even got a connection error from ssh-add, and I had to manually start ssh-agent (never happened before though).
